# SSL on multi-language site

Tags: expresso-store, htaccess, ssl

I'm trying to get the checkout template working with SSL. When I set the Require SSL parameter to YES in CP / Store / General. loading the checkout template (https://www.mydomain.com/nl/store) fails and returning an error page: "The requested URL /nl/store/checkout was not found on this server".

I've used a multi language set-up where each country has it's on folder in the root, containing a separate .htacces and index.php file. Other then the SSL issues the site and store functioning properly.

### .htacces:

```
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /nl/index.php/$1 [L]
```

### index.php:

```
$assign_to_config['site_index'] = '';
$assign_to_config['site_url'] = 'http://www.mydomain.com/nl/'; 
$assign_to_config['site_404'] = 'site/404';
$assign_to_config['global_vars'] = array(
    "country_code" => "nl",
    "language" => "Nederlands"
); // This array must be associative
```

Comment: Any chance of just making your whole site HTTPS? It would make these issues disappear really quickly :)

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

```
$assign_to_config['site_url'] = 'http://www.mydomain.com/nl/';
```

to

```
$assign_to_config['site_url'] = '//www.mydomain.com/nl/';
```

we haven't done with Store before, but had to use it in other areas of sites we've done, so that the page will properly load as SSL. The process is called '[protocol-relative](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/)'. We were having a slew of SSL issues, due to assets— images, css files, javascripts, etc. All that used `http://` when we were trying to initiate `https://` and that helped, tremendously.

Can't say if it will work, but no harm in trying.